# Where to find http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics?

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, soapheader

On our web-service we receive several requests with elements from the http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics namespace in the SOAP header. Instead of just ignoring these elemtns, we would like to validate them instead. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a place for downloading the schema. If I try with the schema-url itself, all I get is a 404. Even Google has no clue!!